# How do I consume a key event in Scala reactions

Tags: scala, awt

Suppose there is a "reactions" block such as

```
this.reactions += {
  case KeyReleased(src, key, mod, _) => {
  // do some stuff
  // but how to consume this KeyEvent??
  }
}
```

After doint "some stuff" I want to consume the KeyEvent, but I do not know how. Looking into sources on Component.scala I have found how the KeyReleased event is constructed:

```
object keys extends Publisher {
  peer.addKeyListener(new KeyListener {
    def keyPressed(e: java.awt.event.KeyEvent) { publish(new KeyPressed(e)) }
    def keyReleased(e: java.awt.event.KeyEvent) { publish(new KeyReleased(e)) }
    def keyTyped(e: java.awt.event.KeyEvent) { publish(new KeyTyped(e)) }
  })
}
```

The java.awt.event.KeyEvent is used as a constructor parameter, but the KeyReleased **case class** has this signature

```
case class KeyReleased(val source: Component, key: Key.Value, val modifiers: Key.Modifiers, 
                location: Key.Location.Value)
               (val peer: java.awt.event.KeyEvent) extends KeyEvent {
def this(e: java.awt.event.KeyEvent) = 
this(UIElement.cachedWrapper[Component](e.getSource.asInstanceOf[JComponent]), 
    Key(e.getKeyCode), e.getModifiersEx, Key.Location(e.getKeyLocation))(e) 
}
```

and therefore I cannot access the KeyEvent parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to unpack the KeyReleased event in the case statement reaction. Just matching on the Event itself will allow you to call consume on it.

```
reactions += {
    case e: KeyReleased => {
        println(e.source, e.key, e.modifiers)
        e.consume
    }
}
```